# what is the number of turn of my secondary and primary coil?

Tags: transformer

I want to make a 800-1000w transformer for ips. I have bought all component to make it. 
here is the list.

- CABLE:-
  SWG 21 for primary winding,
  SWG 12 for secondary winding,
- CORE:-
  4.5 inch
- FORMER/bubbin:-
  3.05"/7.747c.m.
  1.6"/4.064c.m.

The transformer is make by 12-0-12V secondry and 0/N-140-220-260V
Plz help me to find out how many turn will be in primary winding and secondary winding

Comment: If you're lucky, the core specification will have a turns per volt recommendation. If not, you'll need to work it out from the core characteristics yourself.

Comment: As you've already bought the wire, fill half the bobbin with a primary, the other half with a secondary, count the turns you have, then check my design method to see whether those are enough!

Comment: Urms=4.44fNAB. All units in are SI.

Comment: Plz help me? Please use proper English on an experts site.

Answer (score 5):

Always start with the primary winding and wind the secondary to suit the turns ratio aka voltage ratio needed.

The biggest golden rule with a transformer is to avoid excessive saturation of the core. You don't need to concern your self about the secondary winding at this stage because saturation is a function of the primary winding and its inductance.

For instance, if the primary inductance were (say) 10 henries and had 220V applied at 50 Hz, the magnetization current is: -

\$\dfrac{220}{2\pi\times 50 \times 10}\$ = 70 mA.

This current times number of turns (say) 1000 = 70 ampere-turns. This is called MMF (magneto motive force). However, to work out if the core is saturating you need to know H (magnetic field strength) and this is MMF/distance. Distance is the mean length around the core: -

[image]

The green dotted line in the diagram above is the distance I'm referring to. You can physically estimate it or look at the data sheet for the core you have purchased. For 1 kW, the distance should probably be around 300 mm. This is a ballpark figure and could easily be higher.

So this means that H is around 70/0.3 ampere-turns-per-metre = 233 At/m. However, this is an RMS H value and the peak is going to be about 330 At/m

How much flux density does 330 At/m give you for (say) silicon steel laminations: -

[image]

By my reckoning, that's a little over 1 tesla and, as you can see this is just taking the BH curve into a little bit of saturation (acceptable).

So, to answer your question, research the material properties of the laminations/core and get the BH curve for that material. Choose a flux density that is "pushing" a little bit into saturation and work out the peak H value. From that peak H value divide by \$\sqrt2\$ to get an RMS value.

Next, divide this by the mean length around the core to get ampere-turns (MMF). Then, you have to look at the data on the core (as a whole) to work out what inductance you get for "so many" turns of winding. Here you need to do a bit of trial and error (remembering that inductance is largely proportional to turns-squared).

You are going to be aiming for about 10 henries (or thereabouts) in my personal opinion and if the turns needed are 1500 then the H field will be a little too large and there will be too much saturation. Like I said there's a bit of trial and error going on at this point but good luck.

Comment: surely Andy it's smarter to sort out saturation of the core via its volt.seconds and frequency, this is independent of core length and permeability, magnetising current just drops out depending on what they happen to be????

Comment: @Neil_UK please leave an answer to this effect is my recommendation. I am basing my answer on how I work it out given the core material specs I come across. I'd like to see that way of doing it BTW.

Comment: answer done, with more characters for a too short comment

Comment: phew, there's a lot of edits there, I'll at least have your upvote for showing the method ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Basic Idea**

The main limitation when designing a transformer is *peak flux density* in the core material. If you under-run this, you aren't working your expensive core material hard enough. If you over-run, you will have excessive core losses, and very excessive magnetising current (Imag).

If you're lucky, the core manufacturer will give you a peak flux density (Bmax) figure, just use that. More often, you will get a range of figures, and for each flux density you'll be given a core dissipation and effective permeability. Or be given a graph of BH for the core, and have to estimate where you think the safe maximum is.

**Design Method**

Assuming you have a figure for max flux density, you calculate the number of primary turns based on
a) the cross section of iron in the core (the iron window)
b) the peak flux density it will take before saturation Bmax
c) the mains frequency f
d) the peak mains voltage (or rms, as long as you know which)

You then calculate the number of secondary turns based on
a) the required voltage ratio
b) increase by a few percent to maintain voltage against copper losses

You then calculate the diameter of copper wire that will use as much of the copper window as practical.

**Worked Example for your Transformer**

Your specification for the core dimensions is not complete, or at least not clear. However, I've shown my assumptions, so if I guess wrong, you can adjust the number of turns based on the actual dimensions.

I assume the centre leg of the iron stack is 3.05" x 1.6". If this is wrong, just scale all my figures by the error in the area.

The area of the centre iron leg is 77.4mm x 40.6mm = 3142u m2, of which only about 95% is iron (the rest is insulation between the laminations), so giving only 0.95 * 3142 = 3000u m2 of iron.

Let's choose a Bmax of 1.4T. If you look at Andy's graph for silicon iron, that's gone round the corner a bit, but not too far, in terms of saturation. Change the answer *pro rata* if the Bmax for your core is different. The flux density will swing sinusoidally between peaks of +1.4T and -1.4T. As it swings through zero, it is generating the peak mains voltage, so we want to know its rate of change there.

It's easy enough to draw a graph of a sine waveform to derive the peak rate of change, or to use calculus to differentiate sin(2.pi.f.t). It's also easy enough to simply remember the formula, peak_rate_of_change = 2.pi.f.peak. I try to remember the formula, then sketch the graph just to make sure!

At 50Hz, with 1.4T peak, the peak rate of change is 6.28 x 50 x 1.4 = 440Tesla/s.

This is the peak rate of change of flux density. The peak rate of change of flux is flux_density x iron_area = 440 x 3000u = 1.32 Weber/s

This is also numerically equal to the peak volts per turn, which is 1.32 volts.

We need enough turns to support the peak mains input. For your question, the max design input is 260v rms. This has a peak voltage of sqrt(2)*260 = 367.7v.

The number of primary turns is therefore 367.7/1.32 = 278 turns.

Obviously you can track back through those formulae and smash all the terms into one long quotient, but that inhibits understanding of what's going on. I prefer to do it step by step, checking for errors and plausibility at each step. If you look in wikipedia>transformers, there is honkin' great long quotient formula with a 4.44 somewhere in it. You try figuring out from that whether you're using all the right units, or dropped any term!

**Now what about Magnetising Current?**

Having got the number of primary turns from the peak permissible flux density, we don't know yet what the primary inductance or Imag is. They depend on the iron path length, and the iron relative permeability, and whether there are any air-gaps. The better the iron, the higher the permeability, the more tightly assembled the core is, the higher will be the inductance and the lower the Imag.

The magnetising current is rarely a design parameter. If the transformer is designed to stay within saturation, then Imag will be a small fraction of the typical on-load current. As it is in quadrature to the load current, it will add negligibly to the rms current and so to copper losses.

If there is a need for ultra low Imag, for low loss at no load perhaps, then you can use better iron, more primary turns, or best a toroidal core that doesn't have the air-gaps than E_Is have.

Note that it is notoriously difficult to reassemble and E-I core with an air-gap less than 0.1mm (thickness of a sheet of paper), especially for amateurs. For a core of magnetic length 250mm and permeability 2500, a 0.1mm air-gap will **halve** the *effective* permeability to 1250, doubling Imag from a design assuming zero airgap.

Although Imag is *very* sensitive to air-gap, the core flux is totally *insensitive* to it. This is another reason why we design with core flux initially rather than Imag.

**Finish off the worked example (secondary turns)**

Calculate the secondary terms as the voltage ratio from the number of primary turns, plus a few percent.

If we use exactly the turns ratio, then the secondary voltage will be correct at zero load. However, the resistance of the copper will drop the output voltage on load. Adding a few percent gives us back our rated voltage on load, at the expense of a higher off-load voltage.

Once we have the full copper design, we can come back here, calculate the winding length, then the resistance, then multiply by load current to get voltage drop, then use that instead of a few percent to do one more iteration.

Or we can just leave it at 'a few percent', because in practice we won't be far wrong!

**and finally ... Copper Wire Diameter**

Calculate the copper wire diameter by taking the copper window area (the area we get to thread copper through). Assign 25% to primary copper, 25% to secondary copper, and the remaining 50% to non-copper, that is the core bobbin, enamel insulation, tape between windings, poor packing factor due to using round wire, poor packing factor due to hand winding, the need for integer numbers of turns per layer and layers, and clearances to reassemble. Anybody that does better than a total of 50% of the window area as actual copper is doing very well indeed.

Once you have an ideal copper area per turn, calculate the diameter, choose the nearest *available* diameter, then calculate how many turns on how many layers you need on the bobbin, and what the build height will be (including interwinding tape). You may need to adjust the diameter to the next one down if the integer number of layers doesn't fit. If the wire is very thick, you may want to split it into several parallel thinner wires for ease of handling. If the wire is *very* thick, you may find rectangular wire or flat tape is available, that uses the space better than round wire.

**And if you have no core data ...**

If you have no data, but have the core, it's possible to throw on some turns, use plastic insulated flexible wire for convenience, and drive them from a low voltage transformer. Use a bulb in series initially, just in case you start with too few turns, remove it when you know you have enough.

The inductance of the winding will determine the current that flows. You would expect the inductance to vary as the number of turns squared if the permeability remains constant.

Use an AC ammeter to measure the magnetising current as you take one turn off at a time. If you started with enough turns, then the current will rise as 1/N^2 as each turn comes off, as the inductance is dropping due to the number of turns.

When it starts to rise much faster than this, it means the core is going into saturation, and reducing the inductance quickly as the permeability collapses. Put a turn or two back on, and you have found the right number of volts per turn.

Comment: Yes you have my upvote on shear effort but I didn't follow the 1/N^2 bit early on. I still prefer my method of course LOL.

Comment: I've moved the 1/n^2 to the end, and clarified it a little. This is how I've designed transformers since slide rules were more common than calculators. I don't need to consider path length, permeability, or air-gap, whereas you do, not sure why your preference then.

Comment: @Andyaka where did you pluck your 10H out of the air from, or 1500 turns? There's no trial and error in my method, which arrives at max usable operating flux density flux for the core in one go, so exhorting the OP to use it is a bit, unecessary?

Comment: The 10 H is just an aiming point for an average transformer primary inductance on 230 V and it isn't plucked out of this air but through experience. The 1000 turns is again through experience and the 1500 turns is just an example of where ampere turns might be too high for the core given the very approximate core length I used in my example. Like I say, this is my way and your way is your way. Admittedly I am more used to designing transformers using ferrites and these parameters are more accessible maybe.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, the lower permeability and lower Bmax of ferrites, with core dissipation rather than saturation governing the maximum usable flux density, does change the design emphasis, pushing the usefulness of the two methods closer together. I may add that caveat to my answer. I'd like to know how you average the inductance for a 6VA and a 600VA transformer ;-).

Comment: I don't have numbers off-hand for those two power ratings and it might be hard to substantiate without looking into various supplier's offerings.

Comment: @Andyaka well that's the point of my method, it works for 6VA and 6MVA without having to import offhand numbers.

Comment: I've not imported off-hand numbers and the point of my method is that is what I use and there it is... up there in plain English. I don't fully follow your method because maybe I am happy that my method works for me and gives me a better understanding of the fundamentals. There is nothing in my method that makes the assumption you have to go for 10 henries or 1000 turns; if you find that the permeability of the core and its saturation limit are OK for fewer turns then this will become plainly obvious as you work through my method.

Answer (score 0):

Also, never build the windings like on the photo of Andy answer, you'll have huge flux leakage when load is applied on the secondary (this kind of sketch is often seen in physics courses, unfortunately). Instead make the two windings concentric on one leg of the transformer (in this case, the other leg is empty since the transformer is U shaped).

Comment: What percentage coupling factor is implied by a "huge flux leakage"?

Comment: If the two windings are one the same leg of the transformer, special care is necessary for a secure isolation between primary and secondary windings. At least several windings of isolation foil between those windings. A better aproach is the use of a bobbin with seperate chambers for the windings.